# Android: Is it possible to send push notifications directly from third party api?

Tags: java, android, mobile

The data that I am receiving is coming from another source which is not pushing anything to Google cloud messaging and I am not sure when the data will be received. So is there any way to directly check in the background if any data is being pushed without GCM if I have code that would receive data while the app is running?

Comment: Your query is not clear to me!!! What kind of data you want to receive and another source means what ? re-furnish your query.

Comment: The question was more rhetorical but say I wanted to notify the user when a new article that was under one of his topics was posted from this api http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/newsapi          how would one go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to Just go through the REST API Documentation [given](https://alchemyapi.readme.io/v1.0/docs/rest-api-documentation), Everything is 
there only.

Comment: Right so if they don't have anything for notifications then I wouldn't be able to send push notifications?

Comment: Yes, But still you can make a sync strategy instead of waiting for someone else will notify you.

Comment: Could you provide an example of a sync strategy?